# phpmyadmin+php in russian

Tags: php, html, utf-8, internationalization

In phpmyadmin I have stored a few russian values, using utf8_unicode_ci encoding. They are shown perfectly in phpmyadmin.

The problem appears when I get those values with php and I try to put them into options of a select, they are shown as "??????".

I've tried changing the encoding in the headers to iso-8859-1 instead of utf-8 but it doesn't work neither.

I've also tried with

```
mb_convert_encoding($str, 'UTF-8', 'auto');
```

but no change :(

Any other idea??

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a MySQL DB/connection, use `mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");` before your run your query, though a better alternative is [mysql_set_charset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php).

Also ensure you have the entry:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

In the header section of your page.

If you're using PDO, change your connection to:

```
$PDO_connection = new PDO("mysql:host=".$db['host'].";dbname=".$db['name'],
$db['user'], $db['pword'],
array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8")
```

Comment: http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php - "Using mysql_query() to execute SET NAMES .. is not recommended." - you should use `mysql_set_charset()` - that's not an answer to the "Why the -1" as I didn't -1 you, just a suggestion to change the `mysql_query()` part of your answer ;)

Comment: There is a note to that effect, though admittedly it could be clearer +1

Answer (score 1):

> I've tried changing the encoding in the headers to iso-8859-1 instead of utf-8

What for? what's the point in changing right encoding that support russian characters to wrong one that doesn't?

In order to achieve proper encoding on your page, you u have to do 2 things:

1. To tell the database what encoding you're expecting your data in. It should be done with  `mysql_set_charset('utf8')` (or similar function of other library if you'r using one) where `utf8` is the name of the encoding in mysql lingo.
2. to tell a browser what encoding your page in. it should be done with `Content-type` HTTP header, using `header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` and nothing else.

Comment: Before anyone poses the question, yes, it **is** "utf8" when setting it in the database connection and "utf-8" in the HTTP header :P